# proc gchart stacked bar with attached table annotate months

Tags: sas

I'm trying to recreate a graph that looks like this:
It's a stacked bar graph with many types of visits, with the values shown in an attached data table and 2 types of goal lines.

[image]

My data looks like this (I wasn't sure how to create sample code):

[image]

I transformed the data so it's long:

[image]

I'm basing my method from [this](https://communities.sas.com/t5/Graphics-Programming/Stacked-bar-graph-w-table-annotation/m-p/485126).

In the example, if I run the first annotate portion (anno_values) using the example data from the thread, everything runs fine.  However, using a similar setup but accounting for more groups (Visit1, Visit2, etc.) I keep getting this error message:

```
NOTE: ERROR DETECTED IN ANNOTATE= DATASET WORK.ANNO_VALUES.
      MINIMUM VARIABLES NOT MET - AMBIGUITY PREVENTS SELECTION
NOTE: ERROR LIMIT REACHED IN ANNOTATE PROCESS. PROCESSING IS TERMINATED.
NOTE: PROCESSING TERMINATED BY INDIVIDUAL ERROR COUNT.
NOTE:     1 TOTAL ERRORS.

 data anno_values; set long2;
format xc monyy.; informat month monyy.; 
xsys='2'; ysys='3'; hsys='3'; when='a';
function='label'; position='5'; 
xc=month; 
if type='Total' then do;
 y=15; 
 text=trim(left(value));
 output;
 end;
if type='Visit1' then do;
 y=7; 
 text=trim(left(value));
 output;
 end;
 if type='Visit2' then do;
 y=0;
 text=trim(left(value));
 output;
 end;
 if type='Visit3' then do;
 y=-7;
 text=trim(left(value));
 output;
 end;
run;



proc gchart data=long2 anno=anno_values;
vbar month / type=sum sumvar=value discrete
 subgroup=type nolegend
  raxis=axis1 maxis=axis2
 coutline=gray77;
run; quit;
```

I'm not sure if it's the months that causing the issue, but couldn't get further than the first step.

Comment: As indicated on communities.sas.com, using GCHART is harder and it does not provide the same quality graphs.

Answer (score 0):

There are macros installed with SAS/Graph that will help you construct a proper annotation data set.  The macro is name `dclanno`, meaning *declare annonation variables*.

Add these lines to your code:

```
%annomac  /* compiles the SAS/Graph annotation macros */

data myAnno;
  /* The dclanno macro, part of the annomac package does code generation
   * for defining the annotation variables in the PDV
   */
  %dclanno;
```

`dclanno` is part of the `annomac` package found in your installation at SASHOME\SASFoundation\9.4\core\sasmacro.

Here is a link to another example of [A stacked vbar chart annotated to display counts of another subgroup](https://www.devenezia.com/downloads/sas/samples/#stacked-vbar-chart)

Comment: That's helpful, I'll have to take a look at that.